# PHP: Create copies of files from outside public_html

Tags: php, mysql

Security wise, is it ok to save uploaded files (upon upload) outside of the `public_html` folder for security then once they need to be accessed, a tmp copy will be created in `public_html` until the session expires? Or should I just stick with hashing the name and saving the file in `public_html`?

This just crossed my mind and would like to know if this can some technique to properly handle file uploads.

Comment: "until the session expires" -- how do you know when it happens? Also - explain the general task. Why do you treat the copied file safer than stored persistently.

Comment: Rather than make a copy, I'd use a symlink

Comment: Leave them outside the web root and write a script that handles access and output. Security wise, that is. Hashing the file name has just about zero impact on security, and keeping a temporary copy is as bad as a permanent one.

Comment: What is your general purpose?